# Free alternative to Cisco's Virtual Internet Routing Lab (VIRL)

Tags: networking, simulation

I'm studying for a Cisco exam (CCNA). I already have Cisco's ***Packet Tracer*** software (which you can get for free). My exam book further provides a free version of the ***Pearson Network Simulator Lite*** and something called ***Config Labs***, however it says that this will be insufficient to prepare for the exam. The book recommends, at a minimum, the ***Virtual Internet Routing Lab*** (VIRL).

Since my career is in mathematical sciences and I'm just getting into this out of personal interest, thinking maybe I can apply my skillset to a networking context afterwards, this is all self funded. Between the books, video lectures, and exam fees, I'm all tapped out.

Is there a good free alternative to VIRL and/or other relevant Cisco products (like their virtual learning labs, ***Cisco CCNA Routing and Switching 200-125 Network Simulator***, the full version of ***Pearson Network Simulator***, etc).

Comment: Check out GNS3. It's good for layer 3 stuff.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: network simiulator software:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23215/13043